# How to group by a temp var by as using gorm gen

Tags: grails-orm

I want to group the data by frac

```
query := lT.WithContext(ctx).
    Select(
        lT.RouteID,
        lT.TimeCost.Avg().As("avg_time_cost"),
        lT.Timestamp.Sub(beginDate).Div(gap).Floor().As("frac"),
    ).
    Where(lT.RouteID.In(application_id...), lT.Timestamp.Between(beginDate, endDate)).
    Group(lT.RouteID, lT.Timestamp.Sub(beginDate).Div(gap).Floor()).
    Order(lT.Timestamp.Sub(beginDate).Div(gap).Floor(), lT.RouteID)
```

but the Group() can not get bginDate and gap, so how to do it